# Make a container transparent only when another div is over

Tags: css

So as exposed in the title, i'd like to make a part of a container transparent, but only where there is another div, I know I can't tell it clearly, then I made an example :

[image]

I don't know if it is possible doing this, using ONLY CSS, I can't use JQuery, not even Javascript.

Thank you in advance for your answers :)

Comment: If the background image is fixed, you can simply do this by assigning the same background image to that second div ...

Comment: It is not possible as CSS do not have conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

No, this can't be done with CSS alone. However, as CBroe has said, you could apply the same background image to the second/inner  to give the illusion that it's transparent.